# attributeerror: partially initialized module 'turtle' has no attribute 'bgcolor'

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-turtle

When I use turtle no matter what I get this error message:

```
File "[REDACTED FOR SECURITY]", line 1, in <module>
    from turtle import *
  File "[REDACTED FOR SECURITY]", line 5, in <module>
    turtle.bgcolor('black')
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'turtle' has no attribute 'bgcolor' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I wasn't even using `turtle.bgcolor()`.

Here is my code, to draw a fern:

```
from turtle import *
import random

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(15)
pen.color("blue")
pen.penup()

x = 0
y = 0
for n in range(110000):
    pen.goto(65 * x, 37 * y - 252)  # 57 is to scale the fern and -275 is to start the drawing from the bottom.
    pen.pendown()
    pen.dot()
    pen.penup()
    r = random.random()  # to get probability
    r = r * 100
    xn = x
    yn = y
    if r < 1:  # elif ladder based on the probability
        x = 0
        y = 0.16 * yn
    elif r < 86:
        x = 0.85 * xn + 0.04 * yn
        y = -0.04 * xn + 0.85 * yn + 1.6
    elif r < 93:
        x = 0.20 * xn - 0.26 * yn
        y = 0.23 * xn + 0.22 * yn + 1.6
    else:
        x = -0.15 * xn + 0.28 * yn
        y = 0.26 * xn + 0.24 * yn + 0.44
```

Comment: you set `[REDACTED FOR SECURITY]` but there can be more important information for this problem - did you save code in file `turtle.py` ? If you have file with name `turtle.py` then it tries to import your file and it can't find `bgcolor` in your file. Rename your file.

Comment: if you want to use `turtle.Turtle()` then you need `import turtle` instead of `from turtle import *`. Besides `import *` is not preferred - see [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/devpeps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in this answer, you need to import the `turtle` module itself, instead of only importing all of its attributes:

```
import turtle
```

Thee reason is because you have

```
pen = turtle.Turtle()
```

where if you didn't do `import turtle`, the `turtle` in that line wouldn't be defined.

---

One thing I want to address is that you don't need the turtle pen to be down in order for the `turtle.dot()` method to work, hence reducing the

```
    pen.pendown()
    pen.dot()
    pen.penup()
```

to

```
    pen.dot()
```

will effectively improve your program's efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @furas about your `import` statement is on the mark (+1).  Based on other calls in your code, e.g. `speed(15)` and `pendown()` before `dot()`, it's clear you've not worked with turtle before and/or read its documentation.

If I were writing this for pure speed, I'd do something more like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import random

x, y = 0, 0

def draw():
    global x, y

    turtle.goto(65 * x, 37 * y - 252)
    turtle.dot()

    r = random() * 100  # to get probability

    xn, yn = x, y

    if r < 1:  # elif ladder based on the probability
        x = 0
        y = 0.16 * yn
    elif r < 86:
        x = 0.85 * xn + 0.04 * yn
        y = -0.04 * xn + 0.85 * yn + 1.6
    elif r < 93:
        x = 0.20 * xn - 0.26 * yn
        y = 0.23 * xn + 0.22 * yn + 1.6
    else:
        x = -0.15 * xn + 0.28 * yn
        y = 0.26 * xn + 0.24 * yn + 0.44

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(draw)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.color('blue')
turtle.penup()

draw()

screen.exitonclick()
```

This will run forever until you click on the window, whereupon it will stop and disappear.

[image]

Comment: Every time I import turtle I get the same message error. If i just do import turtle, I get that message error.

Comment: @user14545830, one error that leads to a message like the one you describe is if you name one of your own source files **turtle.py** -- Python then confuses it with the **turtle.py** library and you get errors.  Something to look for.